# Using auth0 with keycloak

Tags: keycloak, auth0

I would like to be able to use auth0 as identity provider, so having all login part done through auth0 and using keycloak as authorization manager, so having all user permission management done through keycloak. Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 10):

Yes there is.

Keycloak allows you to create mappers for custom identity providers, so that you can extract roles and attributes from your provider to keycloak. That way you will be able to use ABAC or RBAC in Keycloak, with still user permission management done through Auth0.

First you can add Auth0 as an identity provider through OpenID Connect or SAML2. Go to your Auth0 app config > advanced setttings > endpoints to get all the required information to create a new identity provider.

Then you need to create mappers in your identity provider, so you can import attributes or roles from Auth0 token. Documentation is available at https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/server_admin/index.html#_mappers

Now your user in Keycloak will have attributes and roles you mapped from Auth0.

Next enable Authorization on your client. You can now define your resources, scopes, policies and permissions in it. See https://www.keycloak.org/docs/4.8/authorization_services/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There was a mistake in my original question, the point was to fully delegate permissions to keycloak, but I guess from what you say that you can have some sort of mapping between a user in auth0 and in keycloak and be able from that point to have all permissions in keycloak ?